# Why does "directory service"-and-cookies-based SSO only work within ONE internet domain?

Tags: single-sign-on

In Chapter 3 of the book [Solving Identity Management in Modern Applications: Demystifying OAuth 2, OpenID Connect, and SAML 2](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/63839656-solving-identity-management-in-modern-applications), there's a section saying:

> #### Early SSO Servers
>
> Several types of what became known as identity and access management (IAM) or single sign-on (SSO) servers provided further improvement. Early SSO servers leveraged the identity information in a directory service, but provided a layer on top of the directory service that maintained a session to remember users that had already authenticated. The way they worked varied, but in a typical approach, an application could redirect a user’s browser to an SSO server to have the user authenticated there, and the application would receive the authentication results in a secure, predetermined fashion. If a user accessed a second application, shortly after they authenticated for the first application, the second application redirected the user’s browser to the SSO server, and the SSO server would detect the user’s existing session and redirect them back to the application with a success status without prompting the user for credentials again.
>
> The introduction of single sign-on servers offered many advantages over directory services. Users benefited from the ability to access multiple applications with a single authentication. Security teams appreciated that the user’s static directory password was only exposed to the SSO server, instead of to each application the user accessed. IT departments were happy because it gave them a single place to implement authentication policy and stronger authentication mechanisms.
>
> Unfortunately, there were some disadvantages with early SSO servers in practice. The interaction between applications and SSO servers was somewhat proprietary, and SSO products were often time-consuming to implement. This meant their adoption was more evident in larger companies with resources to integrate applications with SSO servers. A more significant limitation was that ***single sign-on relied on cookies which, due to browser restrictions on cookie access, meant the solutions worked within one Internet domain such as `www.mycompany.com`. As many companies were becoming interested in external Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) applications, this was a limiting restriction.***

I don't understand the sentences which I made bold & italic:

- If this SSO solution works in a redirecting flavor, what does it have to do with cookies?
- If it is a limitation to use external SaaS applications, how does it work with an in-house domain such as `app1.mycompany.com`, which is different from `www.mycompany.com`.

I've searched on Google and asked ChatGPT & Bard. They didn't give me a reasonable answer.

Comment: Cookies are automatically available on all "subdomains" of the host they were set for. If the cookie was set for `mycompany.com`, then it is available on `mycompany.com`, `www.mycompany.com` and `app1.mycompany.com`.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! Maybe it's because I don't know how 'Early SSO Servers' work... It's quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

[Synchronizing Single Sign-On (SSO) with a Domain Cookie](https://www.fusionspan.com/blog/synchronizing-single-sign-on-sso-with-a-domain-cookie-part-1-an-overview/) seems like the case. Cookies are used to extract token by the second app.

But the quotes in the question says:

> If a user accessed a second application, shortly after they authenticated for the first application, the second application redirected the user’s browser to the SSO server, and the SSO server would detect the user’s existing session and redirect them back to the application with a success status without prompting the user for credentials again.

Maybe it's just one of the implementations in the old days. And the limitation only existed in cookies-based SSO.